# Developer with SQLAgentUserRole only has View access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-agent

I have a developer who needs to be able to create jobs in SQL Server Agent. They are part of the security group SQLDA and I granted that group SQLAgentUserRole in msdb. They still have view only access. Do I also need to grant them db_datawriter in msdb for them to be able to create jobs?

Running SQLServer 2019. Permissions are managed through Active Directory groups.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Windows group account for the developers, if mapped correctly, can create/modify/delete jobs with database role membership of [`SQLAgentUserRole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent-fixed-database-roles?view=sql-server-ver16#sqlagentuserrole-permissions). You don't need to add the `db_datawriter` database role.

> To create a job, a user must be a member of one of the SQL Server Agent fixed database roles or the sysadmin fixed server role. A job can be edited only by its owner or members of the sysadmin role. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver16#Restrictions)

sample [sp_add_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-job-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) code below using SQL Authentication (applicable to Windows Authentication):

```sql
/* map the user correctly*/
USE [msdb]
GO
CREATE USER [dev] FOR LOGIN [dev]
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
ALTER ROLE [SQLAgentUserRole] ADD MEMBER [dev]
GO


USE msdb;
GO
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'dev';  
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job @job_name = N'NightlyBackups';
GO  
REVERT;  
GO
```